# mysql inserts in groups?

Tags: php, mysql

Say I have a website, with 2 users on the site.

Both load a php page which inserts 1000 big rows into mysql, it loads them using a for loop.

Right now, the inserts are crossing, for example, 15 inserts from user 1, then 3 from user 2, then 5 from user 1...

How can I make it so if user 1 loads the php file first, then user 2 must wait until user 1 has finished inserting all 1000 of his rows before user 2 can begin?

Comment: Have you tried table locking? http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/lock-tables.html - though, if the execution time is long enough, the script for "user2" may well time out... and if there are many users it's almost definite that those further down the queue will time out.

Comment: How are you inserting the rows? Are you creating one INSERT statement with multiple values? Or are you inserting each row separately?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use MySQL insert delayed, here is the docs: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/insert-delayed.html

It will queue your insert queries, just when a one has finish the other will begun. But if you want to join all the queries from an user before to send the second query, this will be a lite more complicated, maybe a temporary table in the memory can help you hold the user sessions table before actually make the insert. But I think that insert delayed will solve your problem.

Comment: I am investigating this.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

PHP has no built-in mechanism for synchronizing between sessions.

However, you can introduce a dummy file or a dummy table in your database which contains the information of who is actually using the database. When the user is done, this information should be deleted which means that the database is free again.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of having a dummy table, use memcache, and set a varaible in the memcache whenever a user tries to access the DB, and before granting access, every time that memcache varaible is checked. It can be implementing in the same concepts as semphores in Operating systems are used, to lock the processor.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know the kind of data you're saving and why you need to make the user 2 wait the user 1 finish the inserts, nor which availability you need.
However, I'll move the problem from the PHP scripts to the DB.

If you don't need to access the inserted data immediatley I'll go this way. 
I'd consider to use an intermediate table where you put all INSERTs from user 1 and from user 2 regardless of the uniqueness of the data.
Then, in MySQL I'd write a stored procedure, called periodically from a timed event, which takes all records from this intermediate table and store in the right table, removing duplicates. It depends on your design, it could be possible just using a SELECT DISTINCT or a GROUP BY.

This approach transfer the concurrency problems from the PHP to the Database. It keeps the PHP script very simple and scalable: no need to keep track of possibly complicated concurrency mechanisms and if tomorrow you'll have three or more concurrent scripts instead of just two, just add it and all still works.
From the point of view of the user, you don't have any delay in execution.

The only drawback is that you won't have all data available immediately after the INSERTs because you'll have to wait the DB event to run. But if you write the stored procedure with care, it can be called even every 10 or 5 minutes.

Instead, if you need to access the inserted data almost in real time while inserting, you can partially modify this approach by using a trigger instead of a timed event.
I'll still keep an intermediate table as cushion where put all data, then with a trigger (after update) I'll check if the record just inserted is already present in the destination table and put there only if not present.